# Pixelated image in ps format!

Tags: graphics, postscript

I have a big problem with the figures in my paper. I need to submit a postscript file to a journal. Figures are in a good shape while I directly convert the file to pdf. But while I save the file in postscript format they are pixelated like the photos I attached. Any help appreciated! By the way I use lyx

[image: pdf]
[image: postscript]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I recommend using either [pstricks](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) or  [tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). You can find many good examples showing how to use these packages on TeX.SX.

Comment: Do you maybe have 2 accounts?

Comment: While I export the file in ps format the quality of all figures are terrible!

Comment: Please help me. My mind is exploding!

Comment: If you're using PSTricks, XeTeX might be an option. It doesn't require the DVI-PS-PDF process.

Answer (score 1):

AS @Andrew suggested, you should use TikZ for your figures in order to avoid such difficulties; then you can simply compile to either PDF or PS with good results. You do not say how your figures are generated, but since you include them in your PDF documents without problem but have problems in your PS documents, they are clearly not EPS.  For your PS document they must (well, let's just say that for now) be EPS files.  Your conversion software (which you do not identify) is causing the problem when it converts your figures for you to EPS, but for many formats you cannot reasonably hope for a good conversion.  Hopefully the software you used to generate the figures can also output EPS files, which you can provide instead of the converted files.