# Pixelated image in postscript format!

Tags: graphics, postscript

I have a big problem with the figures in my paper. I need to submit a postscript file to a journal. Figures are in a good shape while I directly convert the file to pdf. But while I save the file in postscript format they are pixelated like the photos I attached. Any help appreciated! By the way I use lyx.
[image: PDF]
[image: postscript]

Comment: this is the same https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238601/pixelated-image-in-ps-format